# Check Login with saml 2.0 authencation

Tags: authentication, express, saml-2.0

I just wonder if there is anyway to check whether another SP is signed in to IDP then my SP will sign in too (ex after refresh page) without request to IP again ? I am using express node server.

Answer (score 1):

In SAML it is not your SP that is signed in, but the user. When the user log in a session is saved in the user browser. When another SP tries to authenticated the user, the user will be redirected to the IDP but as the user is already authenticated, the user will be redirected back to the SP without having to login as the IDP recognizes the logged in session.

Comment: So there is anyway to do that in case different sub domain ? I see that microsoft service could do that when you have signed in one of their services.